# Convert nested dictionary inside Pandas columns into different columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, nested

I have a dataframe 'df' that looks like the following:

```
+----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | category                                                                                         |
+----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 1  | [{'alias': '1', 'title': 'a'}, {'alias': '11', 'title': 'aa'}, {'alias': '111', 'title': 'aaa'}] |
+----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 2  | [{'alias': '2', 'title': 'b'}]                                                                   |
+----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 3  | [{'alias': '3', 'title': 'c'}, {'alias': '33', 'title': 'cc'}, {'alias': '333', 'title': 'ccc'}  |
+----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I would like to convert it into the following:

```
+----+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
| id | category_alias_1 | category_title_1 | category_alias_2 | category_title_2 | category_alias_3 | category_title_3 |
+----+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
| 1  | 1                | a                | 11               | aa               | 111              | aaa              |
+----+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
| 2  | 2                | b                | 22               | bb               | 222              | bbb              |
+----+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
| 3  | 3                | c                | 33               | cc               | 333              | ccc              |
+----+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
```

This is how far I have gotten with the code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df.category.values.tolist())
df = pd.DataFrame(df[0].values.tolist())
```

However, my current method seems to be too tedious. Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

1.define empty list with name you required as columns name.
2.then use iterrows using for loop....
use json.loads or pd.json_normalize.any of them will work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).